# how to take each answer as string

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

how to take each answer as string like:
first question = message1
second question = message 2

```
import asyncio
import discord
import requests
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Game
import asyncio

questions = ["Question 1", "Question 2", "Question 3"]  # specify your questions here
bot = commands.Bot(intents=discord.Intents.default(),command_prefix='+')


@bot.command()
async def poll(ctx):
    answers = []
    for question in questions:
        await ctx.send(question)
        try:
            message = await bot.wait_for('message', check=lambda m: m.channel == ctx.channel and m.author == ctx.author, timeout=30)
                
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            break
    if len(questions) != len(answers):
        pass  # member hasn't completed the poll
    else:
        pass  # member has completed the poll. You can get answers using answers list
```

get nothing

Answer (score 0):

You can append the `answers` list with the `message.content` which is a string.

*The `checkpoll` function is made by me but I don't include it here cause it isn't the answer to your question. If you need it, write a comment.*

```
@bot.command()
async def poll(ctx):
    answers = []
    for question in questions:
        await ctx.send(question)
        try:
            message = await bot.wait_for('message', check=lambda m: m.channel == ctx.channel and m.author == ctx.author, timeout=30)
            answers.append(message.content)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            break
    if len(questions) != len(answers):
        pass  # member hasn't completed the poll
    else:
        await checkpoll(answers,ctx)
```